# How to show other fields on <field/> tag in Odoo?

Tags: python, odoo

```
<field name="product_id" />
```

In Odoo, the default display of the field "name" of the "product" table, but I want to show other fields of "product" table, such as "barcode" field, how should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by extending/overriding the [`name_get()`](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/815c2a324dde5dc55c15c46b36c2ec45f653e22c/addons/product/models/product.py#L369-L423) method on the product model.

Comment: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/orm.html#odoo.models.Model.name_get

Comment: Thank you for your reply